# No se guarda la información de uno de los formularios usando multiples formularios en vistas basadas en clases Django 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un modelo `request_move` relacionado al modelo `products` con la clave foránea `product_id`.

En la vista de `request_move` utilizo dos formularios:

El formulario de `products` y el formulario del modelo `request_move`, con el objetivo de llenar 
ambos formularios y al darle al botón Submit, cree los registros en los modelos correspondientes y me reenvíe a la vista en lista del modelo `request_move`.

El problema es que crea los registros del modelo `products` perfectamente, pero no es así con el modelo `request_move`.

No me da ningún error, simplemente por alguna razón no crea el registro del modelo `request_move`.
Utilizo el método `save()`  en ambos formularios de ambos modelos y nada.

Probando cree otra vista basada en clase del modelo `request_move` pero usando solamente su formulario con su método `.save()` y crea el registro correctamente, el problema es cuando trato de hacerlo con dos formularios a dos registros

Acá parte del código de mi archivo `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from basic_app.models import products as model_products
from basic_app.models import request_move 
from basic_app.forms import products_form, request_move_form
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

#--------Views request_move model-----------------------------

class view_list_request_move_class(ListView):

    request_move = model_request_move 
    template_name = 'view_list_request_move_class.html' 


class function_create_request_move_class(CreateView):

    request_move = model_request_move
    form_request_move_model = form_class = request_move_form
    form_products_model = form_class = products_form
    template_name = 'function_create_request_move_class.html'   
    success_url =  reverse_lazy('view_list_request_move_class')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): # modificar la data que le llegará al context
        context = super(function_create_request_move_class, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'form_request_move_model' not in context:
            context['form_request_move_model'] = self.form_request_move_model(self.request.GET)
        if 'form_products_model' not in context:
            context['form_products_model'] = self.form_products_model(self.request.GET)
        return context # el context toma la informacion de ambos formularios

    def rewrite_post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.object = self.get_object # Accede al objeto, la intancia actual
        data_request_move = self.form_request_move_model(request.POST) # Obtiene la data del 1er form
        data_products_model = self.form_products_model(request.POST) # Obtiene la data del 2do form
        if data_request_move.is_valid() and data_products_model.is_valid(): # Valida los formularios
            request_move = data_request_move.save(commit="False") # Con el commit="False Guarda la data pero aun no la pasa al modelo
            request_move.products = data_products_model.save() # Guarda la data del 2do form en el modelo, esto lo hace correctamente
            request_move.save() # Ahora sí Guarda la data del 1er form en la bdd, Esto no lo hace, no lo entiendo
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()) # Finalmente volvemos al success_url
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(form_request_move_model=data_request_move, 
                                          form_products_model=data_products_model))
```

Acá el código del archivo `models.py`:

```
class products(models.Model):

    code = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # class_product = models.CharField(max_length=20) #selection
    price = models.IntegerField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField()

class request_move(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(products, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    note = models.TextField()
```

Y acá el código del archivo `forms.py`:

```
class products_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = products

        fields = [
            'code',
            'name',
            'price',
            'note',
            'active',
            ]
        labels = {
            'code': 'Code',
            'name': 'Name',
            'price': 'Price',
            'note': 'Description',
            'active': 'Active   ? '
        }
        widgets = {
            'code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'note': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'active': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }


class request_move_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = request_move

        fields = [
            'number',
            'note',
            ]
        labels = {
            'number': 'Number',
            'note': 'Description',
        }
        widgets = {
            'number': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'note': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Como ven en los comentarios explicando el código del `models.py`, el `request_move.save()` no guarda la información en el modelo.

Probé comentando la linea del `commit=False` y nada.

Probé sin guardar los modelos y los formularios en variables y nada.

De cualquier manera, en el modelo `request_move` no se guarda la información pero sí en el modelo `products`.

Quedo Atento y agradecido a sus comentarios...

Comment: Título != Descripción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada se crea solo la instancia del modelo `products`, porque la vista solo esta gestionando ese modelo en especifico ya que se sobrescribe el atributo `form_class` por el form del modelo `products` y tambien por que no se ejecuta el método `rewrite_post`.

Puedo suponer que crees que se esta ejecutando el método `rewrite_post`, pues ahí creas las instancias, etc. Pero no es así, primero que nada de donde sacas `rewrite_post`?, el método que tienes que sobrescribir es el método `post`, por eso no se crea la instancia del modelo `request_move`.

(Antes que nada no te **recomiendo en lo absoluto** que la vista `CreateView` gestione mas de dos formularios a la ves, mejor es crear un vista o form personalizado que lo haga, **pues la vista `CreateView` no fue diseñada para gestionar mas de dos formularios a la ves**)

*Por cierto, la versión de Django no tiene **nada que ver en como se deben validar los 2 formularios en una vista**, se puede hacer, pero la forma en que lo haces no es la mejor, pues hay mejores alternativas.*

---

Ahora, tu vista debería quedar algo así (podras darte cuenta que esta vista y la anterior no tienen mucha coherencia debido a que esta gestionando varios forms):

```
class function_create_request_move_class(CreateView):
    model = products
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'function_create_request_move_class.html'   
    success_url =  reverse_lazy('view_list_request_move_class')

    # No es necesario sobrescribir el método get_context_data(), con esto es mas que suficiente
    extra_context = {
        'form_request_move_model': request_move_form,
        'form_products_model': products_form
    }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        data_request_move = request_move_form(request.POST)
        data_products_model = products_form(request.POST) 

        if data_request_move.is_valid() and data_products_model.is_valid(): 
            request_move = data_request_move.save(commit=False) 
            request_move.products = data_products_model.save() 
            request_move.save() 

            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                    self.get_context_data(form_request_move_model=data_request_move, 
                                          form_products_model=data_products_model))
```

Y listo, te debería funcionar todo correctamente, y se deberían crear las 2 instancias sin ningún problema.

---

Por otra parte, hay varias librerías que implementan formularios personalizados para gestionar varios modelos como [*django-betterforms*](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), y sus formularios personalizados [*MultiForm and MultiModelForm*](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html), o [*django-multiform’s*](https://django-multiform.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), etc.

Te recomiendo utilizarlos ya que son diseñados específicamente para lo que estas haciendo (te recomiendo *django-betterforms*, pues se ve mucho mas interesante) y considero de mala practica lo que estas haciendo con la vista `CreateView`, pues no fue diseñada para ello.

Por ultimo te sugiero leer [*PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), que ofrece convenciones de codificación para el código de Python, pues no sigues varias de ellas, como la forma correcta de nombrar las clases, etc :)

Y bueno eso seria todo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias Julio, funcionó, sólo tuve que agregarle self.object = self.get_object después de nombre de la función. Tomaré en cuenta el uso de  dango-betterforms, MultiForm, MultiModelForm y django-multiform’s, no sabía de esos, gracias. Por otra parte, la PEP 8 la obvié un poco porque estoy practicando con el curso, pero si las manejo, igual voy a revisarlas, tengo tiempo que no las veo, gracias por la observación.

Comment: has podido usar dajngo-betterforms en django 3?? Cuando lo importo en **forms.py: from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm** me da este error **'ImportError: cannot import name ‘python_2_unicode_compatible’ from ‘django.utils.encoding'** Creo no está disponible para django 3 :(

Comment: La verdad nunca he utilizado *django-betterforms*, se poco de el, pero veo un gran potencial en el. Por otra parte el error es porque no se puede importar el modulo `python_2_unicode_compatible`. Estas importando mal dicho modulo.

Comment: Leí la doc de *django-betterforms* y en ningún momento se menciona `python_2_unicode_compatible`, a lo mejor te estas confundiendo, pero `python_2_unicode_compatible` es de Django, si quieres importarlo es así: `from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`. **Pero en Django 3.0 ya se elimino dicha API, puedes verlo en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis).**

Comment: La API `python_2_unicode_compatible`, es para admitir Python2, pero como lo mencione anteriormente, dicha API se elimino en Django 3 y en posteriores, por lo cual no podrás utilizarlo ni importarlo.

Comment: Exacto amigo, me di cuenta de eso, por ahora no podré utilizarlo. Gracias por todo, un saludo.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte :)